# Opening JavaScript Console on Foxit Reader

Tags: windows, javascript, foxit-reader

I'm trying to open the JavaScript console on Foxit Reader (5.4.x), but I can't find a way to do this anywhere in the GUI.

I have resorted to creating a bookmark that runs a JavaScript which executes `console.show()`. Another option is to create a document that has `console.show()` attached to some action like Print or Close, but this requires another tool like Acrobat Pro.

This is very inconvenient. Am I missing something here?

Comment: For those of you wondering how to do this with a bookmark, right-click any bookmark > Properties > Actions > Select Action: Run a Javascript > Add > `console.show()` > OK

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth.. if you install old-but-good version 2.3 (what I have), it has a direct menu for this at "Advanced -> JavaScript Console.."

[JavaScript Console menu in FoxIt Reader v2.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYJoa.png)
I did a quick search online and found foxit seem to be willing to allow downloading old versions, but you may need to ask them for it e.g. [see this question](http://forums.foxitsoftware.com/forum/portable-document-format-pdf-tools/foxit-reader/158953-where-can-i-download-old-versions-of-pdf-reader-printer) on their forum page.